# Solve $\int\frac{1dx}{\sqrt {e^{5x}}(e^{2x}+e^{-2x})^{3/2}}$

Tags: integration

$\int\frac{1dx}{\sqrt {e^{5x}}(e^{2x}+e^{-2x})^{3/2}}$
My try:
$\int\frac{1dx}{\sqrt {e^{5x}}(e^{2x}+e^{-2x})^{3/2}}$
$=\int\frac{\sqrt{e^x}}{(e^{4x}+1)^{3/2}}dx==\int\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{e^x}(e^{4x}+1)^{3/2}}dx=\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt t(t^4+1)^{3/2}}$ by putting $e^x=t$
I am stuck here.Please help.

Comment: This integral can be expressed by a hypergeometric function

Comment: You can try $u = \sqrt t$

Comment: Tried on [integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/), no results found.

Comment: After the change of variable $e^x=t$, the (ugly) solution is fiven in terms of some nasty elliptic integrals.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici They're just too good. Many unanswered questions on this site can be solved using elliptic integrals. See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3895200/area-of-revolution-of-the-following-function-stuck-on-1d-integral/3947012#3947012).