# Area of revolution of the following function, stuck on 1D integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

Given $\gamma(t) = (t-t^2,1-t^3), t \in [0,1]$, I want to calculate the area of the revolution of the solid when $\gamma$ rotates on the $y$-axis.

Now, given I can call $x = x(t)$ and $y = y(t)$, I have the following result:

$$ A = 2\pi\int_0^1 x(t)\sqrt{(x(t)')^2 + (y(t)')^2)}\, dt $$

I do all the calculations and I get:
$$A = 2\pi\int_0^1 (t-t^2)\sqrt{1 -4t + 4t^2 + 9t^4}\,dt $$
But now I have no idea how to solve this. I tried splitting it and using substitution but I am getting nowhere.

Any tips?

Comment: Is approximate value $A=1.1$ fine enough? Or $A=1.101955040955614$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the square root of a quartic with no repeated roots. The answer can only be written in terms of elliptic integrals – but I am going to derive such an answer anyway. All elliptic integrals and functions in this answer follow Mathematica/mpmath conventions.$\newcommand{sn}{\operatorname{sn}}\newcommand{cn}{\operatorname{cn}}$

I use Byrd and Friedman's *Handbook of Elliptic Integrals for Engineers and Physicists*. There are formulas in that book for integrals involving the square roots of general quartics with all complex roots – of which the one here, $9t^4+4t^2-4t+1$, is an example – but they are very unwieldy. So I am going to "soften up" the integral first by making a substitution that eliminates the cubic and linear terms of $P$.

Such a substitution is of the linear fractional type, $u=\frac{t+k}{lt+1}$, $t=\frac{k-u}{lu-1}$. When I put the $t$ expression into $P$ and solve for $k$ and $l$ that make the cubic and linear terms of the resulting expression in $u$ (after multiplying by $(lu-1)^4$) zero, I get one solution as $k=0,l=-1$. So let $u=\frac t{1-t}$:
$$A=2\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{u\sqrt{10u^4-2u^2+1}}{(u+1)^6}\,du=2\pi B$$
$$B=\int_0^\infty\frac{u(10u^4-2u^2+1)}{(u+1)^6\sqrt{10u^4-2u^2+1}}\,du$$
So many powers of $u+1$ in the denominator would make it a pain if I used the tables now. Thus I perform a partial fraction decomposition of the rational function in $B$'s integrand…
$$B=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{10}{u+1}-\frac{50}{(u+1)^2}+\frac{98}{(u+1)^3}-\frac{94}{(u+1)^4}+\frac{45}{(u+1)^5}-\frac9{(u+1)^6}\right)\frac1{\sqrt{10u^4-2u^2+1}}\,du$$
…then reduce the powers using B&F 250.02: let $P$ be a quartic, $p$ a non-root of $P$ and $n>1$, then
$$I_{-n,p}=\int_a^b\frac1{(t-p)^{-n}\sqrt P(t)}\,dt=\frac1{2(1-n)P(p)}\left( \left[\frac{2\sqrt{P(t)}}{(t-p)^{n-1}}\right]_a^b + \sum_{j=1}^4\frac{2m-2-j}{j!}P^{(j)}(p)I_{j-n,p}\right)$$
This reduces $I_{-n,p}$ to a rational linear combination of $1,I_{-1,p},I_{0,p},I_{1,p},I_{2,p}$, and in this case (with $a=0,b=\infty,P(u)=10u^4-2u^2+1$)
$$B=\frac16 I_{-1,-1} - \frac{14}9 I_{0,-1} + \frac{898}{243} I_{1,-1} + \frac{449}{243}\left( - I_{2,-1} + \frac{\sqrt{10u^4-2u^2+1}}{10(u+1)} \right) - \frac{373}{1215} + \frac{77\sqrt{10}}{540}$$
Now let $J_n=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^n}{\sqrt{P(t)}}\,dt$. When rewritten in terms of $J_n$, $B$ has no $J_1$ term:
$$B=\frac16 I_{-1,-1} + \frac{71}{243} J_0 + \frac{449}{243}\left( - J_2 + \frac{\sqrt{10u^4-2u^2+1}}{10(u+1)} \right) - \frac{373}{1215} + \frac{77\sqrt{10}}{540}$$
I have bracketed two terms together because they are infinite when standing alone but finite when combined. Now work out $J_2$ using B&F 225.09 and 361.61:
$$J_2=\frac{10^{-3/4}}2((F(\varphi,m)-2E(\varphi,m)) + \frac{u\sqrt{10u^4-2u^2+1}}{10u^2+\sqrt{10}}$$
$$\varphi=2\tan^{-1}10^{1/4}u,m=\frac12+\frac1{2\sqrt{10}}$$
The sum of the algebraic part of $J_2$ and the other term in the bracket tends to $-\frac1{\sqrt{10}}$ as $u\to\infty$; $\varphi$ tends to $\pi$ in the same limit, so the integrals become complete. Thus the bracketed expression is
$$(\cdot)=-10^{-3/4}(K(m)-2E(m))-\frac1{\sqrt{10}}$$
I can work out $J_0$ similarly using B&F 266.00; it's $10^{-1/4}K(m)$.

To work out $I_{-1,-1}$ use B&F 266.09. Letting $a=10^{-1/4}$:
$$I_{-1,-1}=\frac a2\int_0^{2K(m)}\left(\frac{a\sn u}{1-\cn u}+1\right)^{-1}\,du=\frac a2\int_0^{2K(m)}\frac{-a\cn u}{2a+(a^2+1)\sn u}\,du+\frac a2\int_0^{2K(m)}\frac{a+\sn u}{2a+(a^2+1)\sn u}\,du$$
Of these last two integrals, the $\cn$-containing one evaluates to zero. This is because $\sn$ is even and $\cn$ is odd about $K(m)$, which the integration interval is symmetric over. The same properties allow us to halve the interval of the other integral. Hence
$$I_{-1,-1}=\frac a2\int_0^{K(m)}\frac{1+(1/a)\sn u}{1+(a^2+1)/(2a)\sn u}\,du$$
Now I would apply B&F 361.69 here, but it seems incorrect and there is no errata for it. Using Mathematica (in Try It Online) I get
$$I_{-1,-1}=\frac a2\left(cK(m)+(1-c)(Z + \Pi(n,m))\right)$$
$$c=\frac{2(10-\sqrt{10})}9,Z=\frac{\sqrt{440+161\sqrt{10}}}{27}\log(-3-\sqrt{10}),n=\frac12+\frac{11\sqrt{10}}{40}$$
Finally we have
$$\boxed{A=2\pi(C_1K(m)+C_2E(m)+C_3(Z+\Pi(n,m))+C_4)}$$
$$C_1=10^{-1/4}\cdot\frac{580-247\sqrt{10}}{1215}\quad C_2=10^{-1/4}\cdot\frac{449\sqrt{10}}{1215}\quad C_3=10^{-1/4}\cdot\frac{2\sqrt{10}-11}{108}$$
$$C_4=-\frac{373}{1215}-\frac{41\sqrt{10}}{972}\quad m=\frac12+\frac1{2\sqrt{10}}\quad n=\frac12+\frac{11}{4\sqrt{10}}$$
$$Z=\frac{\sqrt{440+161\sqrt{10}}}{27}\log(-3-\sqrt{10})$$